# Trying to find this font, any help would be appreciated!

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

Just looking for the "teacher" part.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - please take a peek around [tour] to learn about our community, and then look over [ask] and [answer] a question so that you know what make a good question, how to frame it for best responses, and what to expect from those responses! Please also look specifically at this: [https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions] and then edit your question to show us what you've already tried - thanks!